# list only particular type of device

Tags: qemu

The following command give a list of all the devices.

```
% qemu-system-x86_64 -device help
```

I only want the list of Network devices.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qemu doesn't seem to have an option to give that specific list. You can only query the network device *backend* types: `-netdev help`.

You'll hence will have to clean up the output of the full list yourself. For example:

```bsh
qemu-system-x86_64 -device help \
             | awk '/Network devices:/{started=1;next}/^$/{started=0}started'
```